# question mark on the Tweetmeme button instead of the tweet count

Tags: wordpress

Why do I see a question mark on the tweet meme button instead of the tweet count after I have changed the IP address of the server..

This is not showing on our old blog which was posted before IP change..

I have re-installed tweet meme word press plugins but not working.

Please guide.,..